# How to change the color of an active link?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to change to color red of selected link.

For example I clicked the link text dog, the color will change to red because it's currently selected. If I clicked the link text cat the color will change to red and link text dog will go back to default link color.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li> <a href="#"> dog </a> </li> 
   <li> <a href="#"> cat </a> </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:focus`](http://:focus) pseudo-class.

> The :focus CSS pseudo-class is applied when an element has received focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).

```css
a:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> dog </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> cat </a> </li>
</ul>
```

But if you want link to stay red when you click somewhere else on page then you can use js

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass('focus');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('focus');
});
```

```css
.focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> dog </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> cat </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes and i want to click on LI element to activate a HTML link.

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a:focus {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> dog </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="#"> cat </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the :visited selector to style all the visited document links. Check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp